# Typescript Declaration Must Have The Same Variables Problem in Different Dependencies

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, typescript3.0

I have a project that is implemented with .NET Core and ReactJS. Recently, I have updated some packages due to adding a new component in a .tsx file. In order to add **Container** component in the @material-ui/core, it's version has been updated from **"@material-ui/core": "^3.0.3"** to **"@material-ui/core": "^4.1.3"**. ***Unknown*** type in the **typescript** has been provided after the **3.0.0** version then I changed the typescript version from **"typescript": "^2.8.1"** to **"typescript": "^3.0.0"**. Before these changes, there was no problem with displaying the pages. An error has occurred when rendering the page.

I have tried to change the versions again but still, they are not compatible with each other.

My package.json file is added in behind.

```
{
  "name": "bookstore",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development dotnet run",
    "startlive": "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development dotnet watch run",
    "startWindows": "dotnet run environment=development",
    "startliveWindows": "dotnet watch run environment=development"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "^4.6.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.13",
    "@types/react-autosuggest": "^9.3.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.7",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.0.29",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.5",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.1.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6"
  }
}
```

The error that the program threw is written behind.

[at-loader] ./node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:8889:13     TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'History' must be of type 'typeof import("C:/Users/Beko/Source/Repos/BookStore/Client/node_modules/@types/history/index")', but here has type '{ new (): import("C:/Users/Beko/Source/Repos/BookStore/Client/node_modules/@types/history/index"); prototype: import("C:/Users/Beko/Source/Repos/BookStore/Client/node_modules/@types/history/index"); }'.

**EDIT 10.07.2019 / 01.41 am**

My tsconfig.json has the "types" parameter as you see below.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "es2015.iterable",
      "es2015.collection",
      "es2015.symbol.wellknown",
      "es2015.promise",
      "es2015.symbol",
      "es2015.generator",
      "dom.iterable",
    ],
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": false,
    "strict": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": true,
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "typings",
    "bin",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `@types/history` declares a global `History` which is of a different type than TypeScript's built-in one in `lib.dom.d.ts`.

If you're not using the `history` package (I don't see it in your dependencies), the easiest solution is to remove the dependency on `@types/history`.

If you *are* using `history` via an implicit dependency, you can prevent its types from being automatically added to the global namespace using the [`types` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) in `tsconfig.json`. This property should only contain type packages which need to be globally available, such as `webpack-env` (Webpack-related globals). So start with just that one and add more if you get compilation errors about missing types.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // add more entries to this array as needed
    "types": ["webpack-env"]
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added the tsconfig file to the question. I have the parameters "types": ["webpack-env"] in the tsconfig file as you see above but there is no solution with it.

Comment: Do you have a reference to `history` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, I am using it somewhere in my code. I need a different solution from removing the dependency from the project.

Comment: @bekair Did you ever find a solution for this?